# constructor should be payable if you want to use message sender

Tags: solidity, ether, remix

Hi There i was running this code on remix javascript vm. But this gave me error on buy function that constructor should be payable if you want to use message sender. I can't understand the mistake as I am still learning. Thanks for any help.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Lottery {

    address[] tickets;
    address owner;
    uint ticketCount = 0;
    uint maxTickets = 100;


    function buy() public payable {
        require(msg.value == .001 ether);

        tickets.push(msg.sender);
        ticketCount++;
    }

    function currentTickets() public constant returns(uint currentNumber){
        return ticketCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor error is generic and misleading.

It works if you send `1 finney` or `1000000000000000 wei`.

The `require()` is quite specific about that. Here it is in Remix to show a successful transaction.

[image]

Hope it helps.